# need help updating Ubuntu to kernel 3.19

Tags: kernel

please help me update the Ubuntu kernel i updated to 15.04 vivid and it installed kernel 3.13.0-46-generic i want to get 3.19 to resolve a blue tooth error on boot please help me to update for iam a newbie

Comment: You updated to 15.04 from what release? Are you maybe saying you installed vivid kernel in Ubuntu 14.04? If you did, did you use the hardware enablement stack to do so?

Answer (score 0):

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.8-vivid/

Download the packages that match your architecture, 32 or 64 bit.

Then use

```
sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME.deb
```

for each package

Then reboot `sudo reboot`